# Error Exception Codeigniter4 Invalid argument

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, crud, display, undefined-variable

When I try to display the crud, it gives me an error in the foreach. I don't understand the error because I haven't been studying php for long.
I code on Codeigniter4 and here is my code:

```
       <?php
        foreach($membres_detail as $row){      
        ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
            <td><?php echo $row->id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->pseudo; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
            <td>
            <a data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btnEdit">Modifier</a>
            <a data-id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btnDelete">Supprimer</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

**My Controller :**

```
    public function index()
    {    
        $model = new MemberModel();
   
        $data['membres_detail'] = $model->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->findAll();
          
        return view('list', $data);
    }
```

**My Model :**

```
class MemberModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'membres';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $useAutoIncrement = true;

    protected $returnType     = Entities\MemberEntity::class;

    protected $allowedFields = ['email','pseudo','password','id_role','status'];
```

**The Error:**

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable $membres_detail

APPATH\Views\list.php at line 35

<?php
foreach($membres_detail as $row)
?>
```

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: so just edit the essential part of the error message as text into your question.